# Call to a member function getId() on null symfony 5 but other methods in respository are working

Tags: php, symfony, controller, null, doctrine

I'm trying to use the findAll method in my symfony app, the method findOneBy works properly, it looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("vehicle/{id}", name="findById", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function findById($id): JsonResponse {
    $vehicle = $this->vehicleRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    $data = [
        'id' => $vehicle->getId(),
        'VIN' => $vehicle->getVIN()
    ];
    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

but the method find all does not work, and it looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("vehicle/list", name="listAll", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function findAll(): JsonResponse {
    $vehicles = $this->vehicleRepository->findAll();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
        $data[] = [
            'id' => $vehicle->getId(),
            'VIN' => $vehicle->getVIN()
        ];
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

the error I'm getting is the following, for some reason is telling me that the method findById is wrong alltough is working, here is an image of the stack trace
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1jxt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because vehicle/list is after vehicle/{id} function.
Its getting id as a ‘List’

You can put listAll function before findById or u can use priority annotations.

which is

```
/**
 * @Route("vehicle/list", name="listAll", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function findAll(): JsonResponse {
    $vehicles = $this->vehicleRepository->findAll();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
        $data[] = [
            'id' => $vehicle->getId(),
            'VIN' => $vehicle->getVIN()
        ];
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
}

/**
 * @Route("vehicle/{id}", name="findById", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function findById($id): JsonResponse {
    $vehicle = $this->vehicleRepository->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    $data = [
        'id' => $vehicle->getId(),
        'VIN' => $vehicle->getVIN()
    ];
    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Also if you use type hint on findById function, you will able to get 404 if id does not exist.

for example

```
/**
 * @Route("vehicle/{vehicle}", name="findById", methods={"GET"})
 * @param Vehicle          $vehicle
 */
 public function findById(Vehicle $vehicle): JsonResponse {
        $data = [
            'id' => $vehicle->getId(),
            'VIN' => $vehicle->getVIN()
        ];
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I put the findById function at the very bottom of my class and put the type hint and it's working properly. Thanks!